# Unable to go straight ahead with move_base

Tags: navigation, dwa, ros-kinetic, local-planner, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our robot is just turning on itself, whatever we ask it.
It is heavy and has an important inertia.

However, the turning direction keeps to be the same. We wonder why it does not go straight ahead.

Here is the launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS" />
    <rosparam file="$(find mv_fiveco)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find mv_fiveco)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find mv_fiveco)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find mv_fiveco)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find mv_fiveco)/param/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Here is `base_local_planner_params.yaml` :

```
controller_frequency: 2.0  

TrajectoryPlannerROS:

# Robot Configuration Parameters
  max_vel_x: 0.06
  min_vel_x: 0.01 # forward
  max_vel_theta: 0.02
  min_vel_theta: -0.02
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.01

  acc_lim_theta: 0.005
  acc_lim_x: 0.01
  acc_lim_y: 0.0

  holonomic_robot: false

# Goal Tolerance Parameters
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.5
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true

  meter_scoring: true
```

Here is `costmap_common_params.yaml`:

```
footprint: [[-0.65, -0.33], [-0.65, 0.33], [0.65, 0.33], [0.65, -0.33]]
obstacle_range: 1.5
raytrace_range: 2.0
inflation_radius: 0.45
robot_base_frame: base_footprint
width: 20
height: 20
resolution: 0.05
transform_tolerance: 0.8
observation_sources: scan
scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

Here is `global_costmap_param.yaml`:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 1.5
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  static_map: true
  transform_tolerance: 1.0
  resolution: 0.1
```

Here is `local_costmap_param.yaml`:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 1.5
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
```

Here is a [bagfile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YFhWHhP6ewiF8oQcunXVo3GOE1iNbUXD).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291204/unable-to-go-straight-ahead-with-move_base/) by [pl.guhur](https://answers.ros.org/users/32356/pl.guhur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-15**:
Can you view the `/cmd_vel` topic using `rostopic echo /cmd_vel` to find out what commands are being given to the robot. You may need to add update the topic name to match that of your robot.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-05-15**:
Any particular reason you're using TrajectoryPlannerROS?

**Comment by [pl.guhur](https://answers.ros.org/users/32356/pl.guhur/) on 2018-05-16**:
`/cmd_vel` showed only rotation and translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @David Lu, we look over another TrajectoryPlanner. DWA brings us what we expected.

---

Originally posted by [pl.guhur](https://answers.ros.org/users/32356/pl.guhur/) with karma: 23 on 2018-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0